# installing php-imap on amazon ec2 linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, imap, php-7.2

I need to install php-imap on amazon ec2 linux 2 instance.
All the php stuff is inside amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 but php-imap package is missing.
Any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I installed it like this.

I downloaded the php source code of the currently installed version in my Amazon Linux 2

```
wget http://php.net/get/php-7.2.8.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror
```

Unpacked it and went into php-7.2.8/ext/imap/

Compiled extension:

```
phpize
./configure
```

I got some errors.

Some U8T_CANONICAL stuff so

```
sudo yum install libc-client-devel
```

Then libc-client.a not found so created a symlink for it:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libc-client.a
```

some other imap library error so:

```
sudo yum install uw-imap-static
```

I got some other errors so the working configure line was:

```
./configure --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl
make
```

SUCCESS!

```
cd php-7.2.8/ext/imap/modules
sudo cp imap.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/
```

Created an ini file to load it:

```
sudo vi /etc/php.d/30-imap.ini
```

added to the file this content:

```
extension=imap
```

restarted php service (you might need to restart httpd depending on your php installation):

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

PHPinfo now contains:
imap
IMAP c-Client Version   2007f
SSL Support enabled
Kerberos Support    enabled

Comment: This solution can be used to install any other extension like installing php-zip on amazon ec2 linux 2

Comment: Perfect solution. Just to complete. This work for different versions I have 8.0.25 and i just needed to do 
wget http://php.net/get/php-8.0.25.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror
. The only step missing is this command to unpack the file: tar -xf php-8.0.25.tar.bz2

Comment: thanks, your answer really saves me. In my case, I have php 7.4 (no longer supported) so I have to get the source via [yumdownloader](https://blog.packagecloud.io/working-with-source-rpms/) and apply your steps to build the extension.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing the **U8T_CANONICAL** error and can't being able to install the **libc-client-devel** on **Amazon Linux 2 AMI** need to do something extra to resolve the **U8T_CANONICAL** error.

The main problem is that libc-client-devel isn't available so we need to do it in another way.

I found [this link](https://omicronthetablog.wordpress.com/2019/11/13/instalar-php-imap-en-amazon-linux-2/) while searching for my problem. The solution that is posted here is solid. The following link that i gave is for those who are not being able to install the **libc-client-devel** will be benifited from the link.

Or you could just copy paste the commands i'm giving below.

1 - `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

2 - `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel`

3 - `yum install epel-release`

4 - `sudo yum install libc-client-devel uw-imap-static openssl-devel`

5 - `sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libc-client.a /usr/lib`

The rest can be followed from respondent.
Again thanks to the person who answered.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here.

I came from debian/ubuntu and i miss a lot of php packages on aws linux2.
I know it's still a candidate and not a final LTS release.  Only worked for a month with this distro and saw a lot of changes and updates. Some php dependencies can be solved with pear or pecl,  but I couldn't get nothing working on php-imap.

php-imap depends on libc-client (maybe that's a problem?)

Here is my solution.

- Search for the libc-client rpm that correspond to your version and
  install manually.
- Search for the rpm that corresponds to your php installed version. In my case it was 7.2.5**-2** about 2 weeks ago. (today is
  7.2.5**-3** ) and isntall manually

> CODE

```
wget https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/x86_64//php72u-imap-7.2.5-2.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm -P /tmp
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/l/libc-client-2007f-16.el7.x86_64.rpm -P /tmp

rpm -i /tmp/libc-client-2007f-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i /tmp/php72u-imap-7.2.5-2.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm
```

> If it fails because Failed dependencies:

```
rpm -ivh /tmp/php72u-imap-7.2.5-2.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm --nodeps
```

I dont like this solution, but can't find for now any other solution more  stable and easy. It will be a pain with updates....

Comment: Maybe other approach could be install epel repos for centos7 and use it to install all php related packages. This could be a more stable approach to maintain versions on php but i don't know how it can break dependencies with amzn2extra repos

Comment: Nobody have a better approach or solution?